identifying wifi device in laptop and deceiphering terminal output information
Overall, happy, just wanting to learn more. Running a HP Elitebook laptop with Ubuntu 24.04, generally using wifi connection to connect to the web. Speed test will give 30-40mpbs up/down, up to a max of about 90+/90+ if physically located next to my Ethernet/wifi device (I believe I understand the why of that). My fiber speed is 200mbps and if I connect directly to ethernet will show about 180+/180+. In wondering why my wifi connection is so much slower, it may be due to limitations of the wifi equipment inside the laptop. I can live with that, but just want to know.
           *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: wlp1s0
            version: 78
            serial: d4:3b:04:79:af:4f
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-39-generic firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.1.38 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:172 memory:b6200000-b6201fff
    *-pci:1


EH rather useless if you do not include what is shown :)

WiFi is almost always slower than cable. There are different versions, a, b, g, n, ac, etc. Which ones does your router and laptop support? You can edit your question and copy and paste the output of lshw command. Format the output as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Agreed that I need to include what is shown, but do not want to display several pages of output...trying to sort out what will be useful.
Realizing WiFi will be slower than direct ethernet, I know this...but if it is 80% of cable speed, why is it not ,say, 150 mbps instead of 80 mbps in close proximity to the router?

it looks like your laptop support both 2.4 and 5 GHz WiFi at the AC level. Does your router support both 2.4 and 5 GHz bands? Which one does it use to connect to the laptop? If 2.4, try switching to 5, and vice versa.

Does your router support the 802.11AC WiFi protocol? If it uses an older protocol such as 802.11N that may slow things down.

@user68186 I thought the router supported both bands, but only the 2.4 light is lighted right now, so am assuming that is the one connected right now. No instructions with the router and no idea how to switch the connection. Also, I do not know what protocol the router uses. It was provided by my service provider a half-dozen years ago. No idea even how to identify it.

You have found the Wi-Fi bottleneck! Ask your ISP if they will replace your router. Better yet buy your own router and return the one from your ISP.

You may want to disable wifi power management and enable aggressive tx, in terminal
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"|sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf
Then reboot

part of the code seems to be truncated at the right margin /conf.d/ something echo "options ...
what follows /conf.d/

@tomkoehler There is a slider at the bottom of the code window to see what's beyond the frame.

@Jeremy31, I executed the code you suggested and observed no change in speed test results. It may be the case that my modem/router device is the bottleneck as suggested by user 68186. I will have to contact Zitomedia, I guess.
